# Table Merging TDs into one cell

Tags: html, html-table

How would I be able to make a table where I put a jquery to add more tds and the tds be inside one cell only and be placed underneath the previous td.

I've searched with 'merge tds into one cell', nothing came up.

TABLE CODE:

```
<table border='4'>
<tr>
<th colspan='2'>sample</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>RULES</td>
<td><input type='text' name='rule1'/></br>
<input type='text' name='rule1'/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Something like that, although I wanted it to be inside `<Td>` so if I use jquery to delete the last rule I would be able to track, if I use `tr.remove` or `td.remove` everything will be removed.

JQUERY EXPLANATION:

I have an add button, which adds more input `type='text'` to the td cell, for rules.

But then if I wanted to delete the last rule, the only way I can reference the id is through table, tr, td. since every rule is inside one td, it would all be deleted.

So how do I make it all in TDs but appear in one cell just like that simple format above.

Comment: Link to your image so that somebody else can add it. More importantly, where is your code?

Comment: Im currently trying to make a table myself with what i wanted. The image was supposed to illustrate it since i wasnt done with mine. 

im confused with rowspan.

Comment: check updated posts sir.